# How to open CSV in python using CSV library?

Tags: python, csv

I have a problem with this code in python. Its return an error:

```
line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 3310: character maps to <undefined>.
```

How can I fix it?

```
import csv

exampleFile = open('example-base.csv')
exampleReader = csv.reader(exampleFile)
exampleData = list(exampleReader)
exampleData
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
examplefile = open(file_name, encoding="utf8")
```